# REJECT equivalent in ply

Tags: python, flex-lexer, lex, ply

What is the flex REJECT equivalent in ply?
For my code I want ply to detect token LETTER and also WORD for the same text, but only LETTER tokens are detected.

```
import ply.lex as lex
from ply.lex import TOKEN


tokens = (
    'LETTER',
    'WORD'
)


@TOKEN(r'[a-zA-Z]')
def t_LETTER(t):
    print('L')
    return t


@TOKEN(rf'{t_LETTER}*')
def t_WORD(t):
    print('W')
    return t


# Error handling rule

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

 # Build the lexer
lexer = lex.lex()

# Test it out

# Give the lexer some input
while True:
    lexer.input(input())

    # Tokenize
    while True:
        tok = lexer.token()
        if not tok:
            break      # No more input
        print(tok)
```

When I execute the code for the input av the output is:
L
LexToken(LETTER,'a',1,0)
L
LexToken(LETTER,'v',1,1)
But I want the token WORD to be also detected.
In flex I have REJECT for this but in ply I coudn't find an alternative yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent to be`REJECT` in Ply. But that's not why your program doesn't recognize `WORD` tokens; those aren't recognised because when Python expands `f'{t_LETTER}*'`, it does not produce `'[a-zA-Z]*'` since the value of `t_LETTER` is a function, not a string.

Using `REJECT` in the `WORD` action in (f)lex might not be what you're looking for either, but in any case `REJECT` is an extremely inefficient operation and is not recommended for modern code. Flex would tokenise `abcd` as

```
WORD abc
WORD ab
WORD a
LETTER a
WORD bcd
WORD bc
WORD b
LETTER b
WORD cd
WORD c
LETTER c
WORD d
LETTER d
```

Maybe that's what you expect, but it seems a bit odd to me. In both Ply and flex, you can achieve similar results by using a combination of pushing characters back into the input stream (using `yyless` or `unput` in flex, or modifying `lex.lexpos` in Ply), and changing the lexer state using start conditions.

Comment: Indeed the problem was that t_LETTER was a function, but now for input 'a' WORD token is detected, but token t_LETTER is not also detected, I'd want both of them to "fire". That do hapens in flex when I use REJECT, because REJECT just makes the lexer look if for the matched token (and only the "bigest" token is matched) it is also posible to exist another matching token (that matches the whole token already found).

Comment: @myke: i know how REJECT works; I even put an example in my answer. Is that really what you want? Or do you just want to match each complete word and each letter once?

Comment: No, that example is not what I would want, actualy for 'abcd' I want to get WORD, but for input 'a' I want to get WORD and LETTER. So for the entire token to get all other tokens that works, basicaly I dont want to get stuck in a single token if multiple tokens work for the same word.

Comment: @Myke: then you don't want REJECT either.